# ColdFusion 11 gives IIS 500.0 error when accessing a .cfc

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc, coldfusion-11

We are testing our cf code (which all works fine on a CF9 Windows Server 2008 machine) for migration to a CF11 Windows 2012 R2 machine. We have a test machine setup and all the code moved over and so far the cfm pages seem to work fine as well as the Application.cfc page but when we call a cfc via AJAX or we visit the cfc methods directly we get an IIS 500.0 error Application could not be found. If I look in the application.log for CF all I see for the error is "Application could not be found. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ""

Anybody else run into this?

Comment: Instead of describing the error, can you copy and paste the whole thing (line refs, code ref etc). Also if you call *the same* method via CFML code, does it run OK? Is it *any* CFC method, or specific one(s)? Actually when you say "IIS 500 error", you mean actually the std IIS error page? What if you opt to see detailed errors, so CF responds with its error message?

Comment: 500 error is not verbose enough - it's more of a catchall. Make sure you enable _verbose_ degug info in the CF Admin, turn on debugging for your IP, then thrwo the error and describe the details. This is best done in your staging environment or dev environment not on production unless in an extreme emergency :)  If you don't see any further details, then you should look in the out log or begin to setep through the code.

Comment: If you want to see the detailed error message, you'll have to allow it in IIS. Pick the site in IIS, double click "Error Pages", click "Edit Feature Settings..." (on the right), change the Error Responses to be "Detailed Errors", and click OK.  At this point the 500.0 error should give more information about the actual error.  Don't forget to change this setting back when you are done if this is a live site.

Comment: Side note, the "application" log often give a summary only. For full stack trace details, try the exception log.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We upgraded the Java SE Runtime Environment to 1.8.0_91 from 1.8.0_66, restarted ColdFusion and it fixed the issue. Find your upgrade here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 0):

Renshi, (or for others finding this in the future), is the request which is failing one where your URL referred to a folder off your webroot called /api?

If so, then the error you got is due to a change in CF11 (update 11) which effectively made/api a "reserved url" for CF, in support of the REST services feature added in CF11.

You can implement a workaround to the problem (assuming you don't intend to use CF's REST feature in ANY CF app) by commenting out the few lines that refer to the "/api" servlet-mapping in CF's web.xml file. For more details, see this blog post:

http://chads-tech-blog.blogspot.com/2017/03/coldfusion-2016-broke-my-api-and-how-i.html